# Is there any way to trigger urlManager conditionally in YII framework

Tags: yii2, conditional-statements, yii-url-manager

I have following code-

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    //'showScriptName'=>false,
                    //'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            ''=>'site/home',
            'logout'=>'site/logout',
            'login' =>'site/login',
            'page/about' => 'page/show/id/1',               
            '<cat0:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>/<cat1:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>/<name:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>' => 'product/single',
            '<cat0:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>/<cat1:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>' => 'product/products',
            '<cat0:[a-zA-Z\-0-9 ]+>' => 'product/subcategories',

        ),
    ),
```

but when I used any site path example-

```
/site/contact/
```

Yii consider it as cat0 and cat1 hence it forwards me towards the `product/products` controller with `$_GET['cat0'] = site` and `$_GET['cat1'] = contact`.

Is there any way out for it?

Comment: as @zakrzu suggested either use a prefix for dynamic rules or add all the static rules before dynamic rules .. as the patterns are same

Comment: Okay i will. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. Your rules say:

`any_word/any_word` will go to `product/products`

i.e. `site/contact` will go to `product/products`

So try this: `products/<cat0:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>/<cat1:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+>' => 'product/products',`

Now `products/cat1/cat2` will go to `/product/products`

For more read this section: [Adding Rules Dynamically](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#adding-rules)